# Read Array of String from Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I saved an `Array[String]` to a Parquet file from Spark.

To read it I use:

```
row.getAs[Array[String]]("result")
```

But get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Here is the result of `printSchema()`:

```
root                                                                            
 |-- result: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How should the `getAs()` be modified?

Comment: Does `row.getAs[Seq[String]]("result")` work?

Comment: Or `row.getAs[scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]]("result")` . @Reactormonk I think you should make it an answer.

Comment: @zero323 `Seq` and `WrappedArray` work.  Do you see any reason to use one over the other?  More interested about performance than usage.

Comment: There is no difference. In both cases you have the same type of object (`WrappedArray`).

Comment: @zero323 I didn't know Seq allows for mutable data types. Good to know.

Comment: @Reactormonk Seq is a very high level trait which simply covers collections which are indexed and have length. It doesn't make any assumptions about implementation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Does `row.getAs[Seq[String]]("result")` work?

Comment: Seems like Spark could use an implicit for this case.  If I get a chance will check it out and submit PR.

Comment: @BAR did you end up submitting a PR or filing a ticket? I didn't see one off the bat and I just got bit by this with 1.6.1